# How can I fix this Flutter xcode build?

Tags: flutter

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 8 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...                                                  

 ├─Assembling Flutter resources...                          10.3s
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         1.5s
Xcode build done.                                           14.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    ld: framework not found Flutter
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
    invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 8.
```

Comment: What troubleshooting have you done so far?

Comment: Did you run `flutter doctor` ?

Comment: Yeah I ran flutter doctor but it doesn't give me any issues on Xcode or Flutter. And on the android simulator it works fine, is on the iOS Simulator that it doesn't work.